# Ordering on probability measures implies equality

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set, $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and $P,~Q$ two probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Assume that $P(A)\leq Q(A)$ for all $A\in \mathcal{F}$. Prove that $P=Q.$

Comment: If $A \in {\mathcal F}$, then $B = \Omega \setminus A \in {\mathcal F}$.  And what of $P(B)$ and $Q(B)$?

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot Brian!